# Is there any way to get rid of Json.NET in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am trying to improve the performance/speed of an ASP.NET MVC 4 website. One area that I discovered as a hot spot and kinda fixed was Newtonsoft.Json.Net's poor performance of de-serialization.   I replaced Json.NET with ServiceStack.Text and now I get a much better performance. That said, when I profile the application I see that Newtonsoft.Json.Net is still the slowest component of the application!

One user story/use case that is vital for us is when a user clicks on "Download" button and then the content is provided by the site for the user to download (we do not provide a static link to the content). From when a user clicks on "Download" button to when the content begins downloading it takes something like 1 seconds. As you can see in the below figure, 254 milliseconds, or 25% of total time, is spent by Newtonsoft.Json doing almost nothing!  Therefore I am really keen on getting rid of Json.NET to gain 25% improvement in performance.

Is there anyway to either remove Json.NET or disable it?

[image]

Comment: how did you "replace" it

Comment: To replace Json.NET, I created a new MediaTypeFormatter using StackService.Text.  I removed all traces of Json.NET from packages.config and everywhere else.

Comment: @Aref did you delete the Newtonsoft dll's from you bin directory?  And did you remove the packages from the package source folder?  You shouldn't just delete stuff from packages.config, but rather uninstall it with nuget.

Comment: @MystereMan I did remove all references and .DLL files. I did a search on the Internet and found out that ASP.NET MVC has dependencies on Newtonsoft.Json. However I am thinking that why Json.Net is spending 250 ms on every request even though I am not using it. And if I can somehow disable it.

Comment: If you are using a custom contract resolver, make sure it's a static instance. Initializing a new instance every time can get very expensive.

Comment: @Aref - Whatever you read is wrong.  MVC has no required dependency on newtonsoft.  Some libraries (I think the oauth perhaps or others) may have dependencies, but this is not MVC itself.  If you deleted the DLL's from the bin folder and the package source, and it's not in your packages.config, then there's no way a new newtonsoft dll would be there.

Comment: @ErikTheViking, you are correct. I removed the DLL files and all traces of them in package.config. Once I did it, the solution was built successfully but one I ran it I got an error saying that Newtonsoft.Json assembly could not be found. I did search the Internet for this issue and came up with the links below, which indicate that ASP.Net MVC has dependency on Newtonsoft.Json:  http://www.programmingrelief.com/5088611/Safely-Remove-Newtonsoftjson-Reference-From-Aspnet-Mvc4-Project

Comment: @Aref - You misread.  WebApi has a dependency on it.  Not MVC.  If you're not using WebApi, you can remove WebApi, leaving MVC in the project and remove json.net

Comment: @ErikTheViking, Now I get it! So how can I remove WebApi?

Comment: @ErikTheViking, and if you write your reply as an answer I would be able to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on information supplied in your comments, you have WebApi installed.  WebApi has a dependency on JSON.net.  You can remove WebApi via the nuget package manager (there are several supporting packages you may have to delete as well).